# Stationarity of an Integral process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Let $f$ be a continous deterministic function defined on $[0,c]$ and $(B^{H}_{t})_{t\geq 0}$ be a fBM with $H\in(0,1)$.
We define a Process $ (X_{t})_{t\geq 0}$ with $$X_{t}=\int_{0}^{c}f(s)B^{H}_{t+s}ds.$$
Am I right, assuming, that $(X_{t})$ is centered, gaussian and stationary?

Comment: I have used Fubini to show that it is centered. For the normality I have tried to argue using a Riemann sum approximation. And for the stationarity I have tried to use $X_{t}=\int_{0}^{c}f(s)B_{t+s}^{H}ds=\int_{t}^{t+c}f(s-t)B_{s}^{H}ds=\int_{0}^{c}f(s)(B_{t+s}^{H}-B_{t}^{H}) ds$. (substitution and stationarity of $B^{H}$.

Comment: Correction: substitution and stationary increments of $B^{H}$.